# SSL using SOAPConnection.call(,)

Tags: java, soap

I am facing this problem, i am calling an `http` url via SOAPConnection.call() method, it works fine, but when i use an `https` url it doesn't work. How to configure SSL in this scenario?

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: i get an `SSLHandshakeException`